Why does the core-mass luminosity relation work?
Why is luminosity of a star with degenerate core and He or H shell burning (RG, AGB or between Post-AGB and PN phase) given solely by the core mass? I understand that the relation is a stable result of modeling but what is the physical explanation?

amount of energy produced is proportional to the core luminosity
